# Update npm dependency of a sub module

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a sub dependency requirement of a npm submodule where passport-yahoo, uses passport-openid that requires openid = 0.5.8 which fixes https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openid/issues/26

My application package.json is as follows:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": ">=1.7.1",
    "express": "3.5.1",
    ...
    "passport-yahoo": ">=0.3.0",
    "passport-persona": ">=0.1.7",
```

What is the best way to update this without having to fork passport-openid and passport-yahoo?

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: I can use https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html to specify module dependencies